# How to allow members to only add/delete files and not be able to add/delete a document library?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, administration, groups, communication-site

I have a communications site. There are following groups: Admin, Member, Visitor.

Visitors can view doc library files. Members can add/delete the doc library and add/delete items to the doc library.

How to prevent Members from being able to add/delete a document library? I only want them to be able to add/delete files in the doc library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have below two options:

1. Create a new group with Contribute permissions:

   This is my recommended approach. You can create a new SharePoint group in site and assign "Contribute" permissions on site for this group.

   - If you want users to only add/edit/delete files and not add/delete libraries, add those users to this group.
   - If you want users to only add/edit/delete files AND also allow to add/delete libraries, add those users to default "Members" group.
2. Change Permissions of default Members group:

   You can change permissions of default Members group from "Edit" to "Contribute". This will not allow members to add/delete document libraries in site.

Follow below documentations for more understanding:

1. [User permissions and permission levels in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/user-permissions-and-permission-levels)
2. [SharePoint site permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/customize-sharepoint-site-permissions)

Comment: By default Member group members can add/delete/edit the site pages, document library?

Comment: Yes, as they have Edit permissions, they can perform those operations.